# Expresión Regular con vocales con tilde en PHP

Tags: php, regex

He hecho una expresión regular para nombres, obligando a que empiece por una mayúscula y siguiendo con una o más minúsculas. Se permiten nombres compuestos o apellidos sin poner límite al número de ellos.

He incluido las eñes y las vocales con tilde y ahí viene el problema... en el caso de poner simplemente `"Úrsula"` o `"úrsula"` la respuesta es errónea. Mi código tiene un Array con varios nombres y se hace el test de cada uno, algunos puestos a propósito para que fallen.

```
$nombres = ["Alberto", "12Pedro", "María García", "Pedro Domínguez Sánchez", "luís ","Luís"," Luís","Úrsula","úrsula","María Úrsula"];
$patronNombre = "/^([A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}[a-zñáéíóú]+\s{1})*([A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}[a-zñáéíóú]+)$/";

echo '<p>### es el limitador para marcar principio y fin del nombre. No forma parte del nombre.</p>';
foreach ($nombres as $nombre) {
    if (preg_match($patronNombre, $nombre)) {
        echo "###<strong>$nombre</strong>### ====> es CORRECTO <br>";
    } else {
        echo "###<strong>$nombre</strong>### ====> es INCORRECTO <br/>";
    }
}
```

Se limita con ### al principio y al final el nombre obtenido del array para demostrar si hay espacios o no al principio o al final (si los hay no debe validar). Observad los tres últimos nombres. Dan lo contrario a lo esperado, en cambio en regex101 sí acepta la regex.

```
###Úrsula### ====> es INCORRECTO
###úrsula### ====> es CORRECTO
###María Úrsula### ====> es INCORRECTO
```

Comment: Hola Javi, bienvenido, fijate si este te sirve: **[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}[a-zñáéíóú]{1,20}(\\s{1}[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}[a-zñáéíóú]{1,20}){0,5}**. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre que uses caracteres con acentos dentro de tu patrón, hay que agregar el modificador `/u` ([PCRE_UTF8](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

```
$regex = '/patrón/u'
```

De esa forma, lo interpreta como un caracter Unicode (en vez de descomponer cada byte).

---

Luego de corregir eso, tu código funciona bien. Personalmente, modificaría estos detalles:

- `\s` coincide con espacios en blanco (incluye saltos de línea), en cambio, usaría simplemente un espacio.
- repetir `x{1}` una vez es lo mismo que no repetirlo y se escribe más fácil como `x`
- en vez de permitir el espacio al final del primer nombre, es más eficiente permitirlo al inicio de todos los opcionales que le siguen.

Usaría:

```
$patronNombre = '/^[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóúü]+( [A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóúü]+)*$/u';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. el modificador ese es la clave. ;-)
Las dos últimas observaciones las tengo en cuenta en otra versión que tengo hecha. Lo del salto de línea si que se me escapaba. Muchas Gracias.